# Zenity does not update the file extension. How to fix that?

Tags: zenity

Zenity seems not updating the file extension of the file you want to save when you have different file format filter and you select a new file extension.

```
zenity --file-selection --save --filename="hello.txt" --file-filter "text (*.txt)|*.txt"  --file-filter "Jpeg (*.jpg)|*.jpg"
```

The `hello.txt` is initially selected but when I select `jpg` in the filer, the name is still have `hello.txt` I wanted to have `hello.jpg`.

Thx !

[image: txt extension while jpg selected]

Comment: After investigation, it seems to me this is how GtkFileChooser works